# result from ajax result into form value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting the results of a query in JSON using AJAX. I can get all the values I need fine and put into  but I cannot put into an text input field? I have tried everything. A snip of the code I am using which puts the user_id and  email in  with the id 'user_id' and 'email' and not the email into input with id 'form_email' is :

```
 dataType: "json",
        data:{email:email,password:password},
        success:function(data){
            if(data.status == 'ok'){
                $.each(data, function(index, e) {

                $('#user_id').text(e.user_id);
                $('#email').text(e.email);
                $('#form_email').value = text(e.email);
```

Like I said I have tried all sorts including getting the value from the span first but seems like a lot of extra work when its there already in the e.email value?

Thanks

Comment: what is the structure of the response ( data variable ) ?

Comment: how do you mean? The variable is e.email  If i use $('#email').text(e.email); it puts the email value into a span ok???

Comment: How about $("#form_email").val(e.email)?

Comment: No it does not work, the only way I can get it to work is $('#email').text(e.email);
     var span_email = document.getElementById("email").innerText;
     document.getElementById('form_email').value = span_email;

Comment: Show your html and example of JSON (data) value.

Comment: You said Input field .... in that case you need to do like this  $('#user_id').val(e.user_id);    instead of "text"

Comment: Thanks Ashish but that did not work either strangely? Its ok I will stick to what I have, its only really for one value so its no bother just annoying, thanks anyway